# How to annotate a queryset with an indirectly related table?

Tags: django, django-models

I've got the following table:

```
class Parent:
    pass


class Child:
    fk_parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Cousin:
    fk_parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to get a queryset of `Child` that is annotated with it's `Cousin`. In PSQL, I would simply write:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM child a
INNER JOIN cousin b ON b.fk_parent_id = a.fk_parent_id
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both relationships are a `OneToOneField` you should be able to use `select_related` and follow the relationships

```
for child in Child.objects.select_related('fk_parent__cousin'):
    print(child, child.fk_parent.cousin)
```